# OrientDB Time Search Query

Tags: sql, select, graph, orientdb

In [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/) I have setup a time series using this [use case](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Time-series-use-case.html). However, instead of appending my Vertex as an embedded list to the respective hour I have opted to just create an edge from the hour to the time dependent Vertex.

For arguments sake lets say that each hour has up to 60 time `Vertex` each identified by a timestamp. This means I can perform the following query to obtain a specific desired Vertex:

```
SELECT FROM ( SELECT expand( month[5].day[12].hour[0].out() ) FROM Year WHERE year = 2015) WHERE timestamp = 1434146922
```

The first part of this question is whether there are any advantages/disadvantages to storing the timestamp as a property of the Vertex (as above query) versus storing it as the edge (or an edge property). In which case I think the query would be:

```
SELECT expand( month[5].day[12].hour[0].out('1434146922') ) FROM Year WHERE year = 2015
```

Although this looks more elegant I have 2 concerns; the overhead of creating new edge types. The flexibility if you don't actually know the exact timestamp.

The second part of the question relates to the fact that once I have isolated the individual Vertex based on time, this is only the head of a hierarchal tree of Vertex.

I could of course get the `@rid` from the above query and then construct a new query but I was wondering how I could adapt the above to do it all in one. For example assume there is a `boolean` property called `active` in all the hierarchal Vertexes. How can I get all the Vertex that are `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer for the first part of your question  :**

Like stated in the use case documentation :

If you need more granularity than the Hour you can go ahead until the Time unit you need:

```
Hour -> minute (map) -> Minute -> second (map) -> Second
```

You get more flexibility by adding more precision to the tree instead of storing a timestamp of the time in the hour.

Adding more precision to the tree has the only advantage of being able to group by smaller time unit in a really efficient way. If you don't need to group by a smaller unit then an hour, then you don't have to add more precision.

The timestamp should be stored in the vertex property because the filtering will be easy and efficient. Check out this blog bost to know the best way to filter on a vertex property when traversing : 
[Improved SQL filtering](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-improved-sql-filtering/)

**Answer for the second part of your question :**

Get the specific vertex and then do your query on the hiearachical tree of vertex :

```
<your-hierachical-tree-query> from (select out('edge')[property = "value"] from
(select expand(month[1].day[1].hour[1].min[1]) from Year where year = 2015))
```

Comment: I appreciate that the granularity of the time tree can be increased but is there an advantage to having 2 records per `second` branch vs 100 grouped into an `hour` branch?

Comment: I don't know if having 100 edges with different names on a vertex is a good practice or not. How much granularity do you need ? Are you always querying all the records in an hour ? You sould expand the time series tree so that you can group by the time unit you want. Oh, and also have I answered the second part of you're question ?

Comment: Second part is good. The number of records is not linear. We might have 5 in 1 second and then nothing for 45 mins. So 1 hour is technically a good granularity because if I go down to the second I need to know the exact second to get the records. I'm just not sure if it's better to use a time stamp as a property of the vector or the edge.

Comment: I updated my answer again with the answer to your question in the above comment :-)